# TwineCompile is not linking changed files in C++Builder

Tags: compilation, c++builder

TwineCompile in C++Builder 10.4.2

Main project with 3 dependent static libs. If I make a change in one of the libs, select Make in the main project, TwineCompile will make the static lib, but it won't link it into the main project.
The only way it will work is if I force a Make on the main project.
Is this the way it is supposed to work??

Comment: Not entirely clear question: What is this difference between "select Make in the main project" and "force a Make on the main project" ?

Comment: Unless there is an actual code change in the main project, selecting Make does nothing and won't Link the changed lib into the project.  So you need to force a Link on the main project by changing come code -- so TwineCompile Make will do the Link. The normal C++Builder Make will do a Link every time.